# Atelier B - Proving simple PO in the context of a loop

Tags: formal-verification, formal-methods, b-method

How can I prove the following invariant holds in the context of a WHILE substitution: INIT = FALSE => size(vv)>0? it seems to generate a blocking PO relating to the loop.

Here is the structure of the B project:

**head.mch**

```
MACHINE
    head

SETS
    ELEMENTS = {element0,element1,element2}

END
```

**utils.mch**

```
MACHINE
    utils

SEES
    head
    
OPERATIONS
      after <-- addElement (before,el) = 
         PRE
             el : ELEMENTS &
             el /= element0 &
             before: seq(ELEMENTS)
         THEN
            after := before <- el    
         END
 END
```

**main.mch**

```
MACHINE
    main

SEES
    head
    
VARIABLES
    vv, INIT

INVARIANT
    vv : seq(ELEMENTS) & INIT : BOOL    

INITIALISATION
  vv := [] || INIT := TRUE 

OPERATIONS         
        Op1 (param) = 
        PRE
             param : seq(ELEMENTS) &
             size(param) > 0 &            
             INIT = NOT_COMPLETE &
             !xx.(xx: dom(param) => param(xx) /= element0)
         THEN
             INIT := COMPLETE || vv ::seq(ELEMENTS)
         END

END
```

**main_i.imp**

```
IMPLEMENTATION main_i
REFINES main

SEES
    head
    
IMPORTS
    utils
    
CONCRETE_VARIABLES
    vv, INIT

INVARIANT
    vv : seq(ELEMENTS) & INIT : BOOL &
    (INIT = FALSE => size(vv)>0)

INITIALISATION
  vv := [];
  INIT := TRUE 

OPERATIONS         
    Op1(param) = 
        BEGIN
             VAR ii IN
                    ii := 1;  
                    WHILE 
                        ii <= size(param) & ii : dom(param)  
                    DO
                       vv <-- addElement(vv, param(ii));
                       ii := ii + 1                           
                   INVARIANT
                      ii : NATURAL1 
                      & ii <= size(param)+1 
                      & vv: seq(ELEMENTS)                    
                   VARIANT
                      size(param)-ii+1                 
                   END
              END;
              INIT := COMPLETE
         END
END
```

The invariant is proved when there is no loop, for example with

```
Op1(param) = 
 BEGIN    
      vv := vv <- param(1);
      INIT := COMPLETE
 END
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the proof of the desired property relies on the post-condition of the loop, which is built as the conjunction of:

- the loop invariant,
- the negation of the loop guard.

Notice that the only property on `vv` in this post-condition is that it is in `seq(ELEMENTS)`. So you cannot conclude that it is not empty, and that its size is necessarily greater than zero.

So you must include in the invariant the property on `vv` that is true whenever the loop guard is evaluated and that will be sufficient to prove your goal.

Here, you could add `ii-1 <= size(vv)` in the loop invariant.